# Cannot export samba user with pdbedit. How can I backup my samba users?

Tags: samba

I have created the samba user `pi` and verified this here:

```
raspberrypi:~$ sudo pdbedit -L
pi:1000:
```

When I try to export it to the file `samba-users.backup` I get this error:

```
raspberrypi:~/pi$ sudo pdbedit -e smbpasswd:samba-users.backup
build_sam_pass: Failing attempt to store user with non-uid based user RID. 
Importing account for pi...failed
```

How can I get this working?